# In CHROME browser Search Suggestion Results not displaying in home page

Tags: search, magento-1.9.2.0

We are using custom module to show "**Search suggestion results**". Those results were displaying in [all pages](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-phone-cases).

but now "Search suggestion results" are not displaying only in [home page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/) in chrome & other browsers, but working in mozilla firefox....

**Edit**

**system.log** : **Notice: Undefined variable: entityId**  in line `$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($entityId);` below is full code :

```
<?php

$catalogSearchHelper =  $this->helper('catalogsearch');
$catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText();
$url = $catalogSearchHelper->getResultUrl($catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText());
$_productCollection = $this->getProductCollection();
$_productCount = $_productCollection->count();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>

<?php $target = Mage::helper('searchsuggest')->getTarget(); ?>

<?php if($this->getMode() == 'list'): ?>
    <?php // List Mode ?>
    <ul class="products-list">
        <li id="autocomplete_hidden" class="autocomplete_hidden"><span style="text-align:center;"></li>
        <?php if($_productCount == 0): ?>
            <li class="notice-message"><?php echo Mage::helper('searchsuggest')->getNoticeMessage(); ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $counter = 0;foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php
            if(!$_product->getSku()){
                $newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($entityId);
                $sku = $newProduct->getSku();
                $_product->setData("sku",$sku);
            }
            $session=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            if($_product->getMinimalPrice()){
                $_productprice = $_product->getMinimalPrice();
            }else{
                $_productprice = $_product->getFinalPrice();
            }
            if($session->isLoggedIn()){
                $groupPrices = $_product->getData('group_price');
                if(isset($groupPrices[$session->getCustomerGroupId()])){
                    $_productprice = $groupPrices[$session->getCustomerGroupId()]['price'];
                }
            }
            ?>
            <li class="<?php echo (++$counter + 1)%2?'odd':'even'?><?php if($counter==1){ echo ' first';}elseif($counter==$_productCollection->count()){ echo ' last';}  ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" target="<?php echo $target; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;">
                   <!-- <div class="img-box-area">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(80, 80); ?>" width="80" height="80" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>"/>
                    </div>-->
                    <div class="content-box-area">
                        <h3><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></h3>
                        <!--<p style="font-size:0.9em;line-height:1.4em;margin:2px 0 0;"></p>-->
                        <!--<div class="std">
                            <?php //echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        </div>-->
                        <!--
                        <div class="no-border price-box">
                            <span id="product-price-16" class="regular-price">
                                <span class="price-label"><?php // echo $this->__('Price:') ?></span>
                                <span class="price"><?php //echo Mage::helper('core')->currencyByStore($_productprice) ?></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        <!--<?php if($_product->getTypeID()=='bundle'): ?>
                        <div class="auto-fright" style="">
                        <div class="price-box">
                            <p class="price-from">
                                <span class="price-label">From:</span>
                                <span class="price"><?php  echo Mage::helper('core')->currencyByStore($_product->getMinPrice()) ?></span>
                            </p>
                            <p class="price-to">
                                <span class="price-label">To:</span>
                                <span class="price"><?php  echo Mage::helper('core')->currencyByStore($_product->getMaxPrice()) ?></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                           </div>
                        <?php else: ?>
                         <div class="auto-fright" style="">
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                         </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>-->
                        </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <?php //print_r($_product->getData()); ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php //exit; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php  if($_productCount): ?>
        <div align="center"><a href="<?php echo $url ?>">View All</a></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**Edit 2**

Issue is because of **Banner slider** that we are using in top , only in home page, once i **disabled that module**, now "Autocomplete serach suggestion" is working in all browsers, but is there any way to fix by enabling that module as it is already working in mozilla firefox....

Comment: on home page search result comes after some time but not able to populate into autocomplete frame. may be js issue

Comment: @GopalPatel  but there is no console errors..... also please check `edit` part in question.....

Comment: Why you are using `$entityId` and you can write this code more optimize

Comment: @GopalPatel that is the `kodematix` extension we using

Comment: provide block, controller and template code

Comment: because in your provided we are not getting what exactly is `$entityId`

Comment: please check `edit 2` part in question.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this line,

```
$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($entityId);
```

with

```
$newProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getEntityId());
```

Comment: i updated your code in demo site , sorry that didt worked for me.....  cleared cache, tried in private window..... [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/)

Comment: dubug the data of $_product object, In which key you get product-Id.

Comment: its working fine in mozilla firefox but not in other browsers like `chrome & opera`.....

Comment: this is the php script, that not depend on browser. For browser you need to check some css issue may be there.

Comment: please check `edit 2` part in question.....